# SQLAlchemy window frames as time interval

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there any way in SQLAlchemy to specify window frame as time interval like this?

```
    OVER(
        PARTITION BY some_col 
        ORDER BY other_date_type_col 
        RANGE BETWEEN '30 days'::INTERVAL PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
   )
```

There's a method `sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement.over(partition_by=None, order_by=None, rows=None, range_=None)` in their docs. By it takes only numeric data as `range_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of SQLAlchemy 1.4.25, there is no built-in support.

## Workaround

1. Implement a `str` subclass that overrides `__abs__` and `__lt__`.

```py
class RangeDays(str):
    def __new__(cls, x):
        obj = super().__new__(cls, f"{abs(x)} day" if abs(x) == 1 else f"{abs(x)} days")
        obj.x = x
        return obj

    def __abs__(self):
        # abs(range_[0]) called in SQLCompiler._format_frame_clause
        return self

    def __lt__(self, other):
        # range_[0] < 0 called in SQLCompiler._format_frame_clause
        return self.x.__lt__(other)
```

2. Patch `Over._interpret_range` to handle `RangeDays`.

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql.elements import Over

_old_interpret_range = Over._interpret_range


def _interpret_range(self, range_):
    lower, lower_ = (None, range_[0]) if isinstance(range_[0], RangeDays) else (range_[0], None)
    upper, upper_ = (None, range_[1]) if isinstance(range_[1], RangeDays) else (range_[1], None)
    lower, upper = _old_interpret_range(self, (lower, upper))
    return lower_ or lower, upper_ or upper


Over._interpret_range = _interpret_range
```

Usage:

```py
# '30 days' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
range_=(RangeDays(-30), 0)
```

```py
# '1 day' PRECEDING AND '10 days' FOLLOWING
range_=(RangeDays(-1), RangeDays(10))
```

Comment: Will do but could it be that this solution doesn't work with MySQL? `RANGE BETWEEN 1095 DAYS PRECEDING AND 1 DAY PRECEDING` doesn't work in MySQL - I need to add `INTERVAL` before the integers and use only `DAY` afterwards. I'm presuming that's why I'm getting the error...

Comment: Yes, I think I tested this answer with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Added question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72163022/11277108