# Implement RANGE using date for window function

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

As of SQLAlchemy 1.4.25 there is no built-in support so I'm trying to use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69606048/11277108). This is my replication:

```
from datetime import date
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Date, func, select, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql.elements import Over


class RangeDays(str):
    def __new__(cls, x):
        obj = super().__new__(cls, f"{abs(x)} day" if abs(x) == 1 else f"{abs(x)} days")
        obj.x = x
        return obj

    def __abs__(self):
        # abs(range_[0]) called in SQLCompiler._format_frame_clause
        return self

    def __lt__(self, other):
        # range_[0] < 0 called in SQLCompiler._format_frame_clause
        return self.x.__lt__(other)


_old_interpret_range = Over._interpret_range


def _interpret_range(self, range_):
    lower, lower_ = (None, range_[0]) if isinstance(range_[0], RangeDays)
                                      else (range_[0], None)
    upper, upper_ = (None, range_[1]) if isinstance(range_[1], RangeDays)
                                      else (range_[1], None)
    lower, upper = _old_interpret_range(self, (lower, upper))
    return lower_ or lower, upper_ or upper


Over._interpret_range = _interpret_range

Base = declarative_base()


class A(Base):

    __tablename__ = "a"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "test"}

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    category = Column(Integer)
    record_date = Column(Date)
    example_value = Column(Integer)


engine = create_engine(<my_connection_str>)
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

session.add(A(record_date=date(2022, 5 ,1), category=1, example_value=1))
session.add(A(record_date=date(2022, 5 ,2), category=1, example_value=2))
session.add(A(record_date=date(2022, 5 ,3), category=1, example_value=3))
session.commit()

stmt = select(
    func.SUM(A.example_value).over(
        partition_by=A.category,
        order_by=A.record_date,
        range_=(RangeDays(-2), RangeDays(-1)),
    )
)
session.execute(stmt).scalar()
```

However, when trying this with a MySQL backend I get the error:

```
Exception has occurred: ProgrammingError
(mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError)
           Failed processing pyformat-parameters;
           Python 'rangedays' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
[SQL: SELECT sum(test.a.example_value)
        OVER (PARTITION BY test.a.category ORDER BY test.a.record_date
        RANGE BETWEEN %(param_1)s PRECEDING AND %(param_2)s PRECEDING) AS anon_1 
FROM test.a]
[parameters: {'param_1': '2 days', 'param_2': '1 day'}]
```

I've tried adapting the solution to add `INTERVAL` before the integers and use only `DAY` afterwards:

```
obj = super().__new__(cls, f"INTERVAL {abs(x)} DAY" if abs(x) == 1
           else f"INTERVAL {abs(x)} DAY")
```

However, I get the same kind of error. I've tried created the strings using `literal` also to no avail.

Any ideas on where I could go from here?

---

**Update:**

The above should return the following SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(example_value) OVER (PARTITION BY category
           ORDER BY record_date
           RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 2 DAY PRECEDING AND INTERVAL 1 DAY PRECEDING)
    FROM test.a;
```

And the following output:

```
+------+
| NULL |
| 1    |
| 3    |
+------+
```

Comment: To help us understand the goal, would you provide a simple example of the data, together with the desired result.

Comment: Hi Rick. The data was contained in my post. I've added the expected SQL and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Patching `_format_frame_clause` as well seems to do the trick:

```py
...
class RangeDays(str):
    def __new__(cls, x):
        obj = super().__new__(cls, f"{abs(x)}")
        ...
...
```

```py
...
def _format_frame_clause(self, range_, **kw):
    return "%s AND %s" % (
        "UNBOUNDED PRECEDING"
        if range_[0] is elements.RANGE_UNBOUNDED
        else "CURRENT ROW"
        if range_[0] is elements.RANGE_CURRENT
        else ("INTERVAL %s DAY PRECEDING" if isinstance(range_[0], RangeDays) else "%s PRECEDING")
        % (self.process(elements.literal(abs(range_[0])), **kw),)
        if range_[0] < 0
        else ("INTERVAL %s DAY FOLLOWING" if isinstance(range_[0], RangeDays) else "%s FOLLOWING")
        % (self.process(elements.literal(range_[0]), **kw),),
        "UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING"
        if range_[1] is elements.RANGE_UNBOUNDED
        else "CURRENT ROW"
        if range_[1] is elements.RANGE_CURRENT
        else ("INTERVAL %s DAY PRECEDING" if isinstance(range_[1], RangeDays) else "%s PRECEDING")
        % (self.process(elements.literal(abs(range_[1])), **kw),)
        if range_[1] < 0
        else ("INTERVAL %s DAY FOLLOWING" if isinstance(range_[1], RangeDays) else "%s FOLLOWING")
        % (self.process(elements.literal(range_[1]), **kw),),
    )


SQLCompiler._format_frame_clause = _format_frame_clause
...
```

FULL CODE:

````py
from datetime import date
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Date, func, select, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql.elements import Over
from sqlalchemy.sql.compiler import SQLCompiler, elements


class RangeDays(str):
    def __new__(cls, x):
        obj = super().__new__(cls, f"{abs(x)}")
        obj.x = x
        return obj

    def __abs__(self):
        # abs(range_[0]) called in SQLCompiler._format_frame_clause
        return self

    def __lt__(self, other):
        # range_[0] < 0 called in SQLCompiler._format_frame_clause
        return self.x.__lt__(other)


_old_interpret_range = Over._interpret_range


def _interpret_range(self, range_):
    lower, lower_ = (None, range_[0]) if isinstance(range_[0], RangeDays) else (range_[0], None)
    upper, upper_ = (None, range_[1]) if isinstance(range_[1], RangeDays) else (range_[1], None)
    lower, upper = _old_interpret_range(self, (lower, upper))
    return lower_ or lower, upper_ or upper


Over._interpret_range = _interpret_range

_old_format_frame_clause = SQLCompiler._format_frame_clause  # backup actually not required

def _format_frame_clause(self, range_, **kw):
    return "%s AND %s" % (
        "UNBOUNDED PRECEDING"
        if range_[0] is elements.RANGE_UNBOUNDED
        else "CURRENT ROW"
        if range_[0] is elements.RANGE_CURRENT
        else ("INTERVAL %s DAY PRECEDING" if isinstance(range_[0], RangeDays) else "%s PRECEDING")
        % (self.process(elements.literal(abs(range_[0])), **kw),)
        if range_[0] < 0
        else ("INTERVAL %s DAY FOLLOWING" if isinstance(range_[0], RangeDays) else "%s FOLLOWING")
        % (self.process(elements.literal(range_[0]), **kw),),
        "UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING"
        if range_[1] is elements.RANGE_UNBOUNDED
        else "CURRENT ROW"
        if range_[1] is elements.RANGE_CURRENT
        else ("INTERVAL %s DAY PRECEDING" if isinstance(range_[1], RangeDays) else "%s PRECEDING")
        % (self.process(elements.literal(abs(range_[1])), **kw),)
        if range_[1] < 0
        else ("INTERVAL %s DAY FOLLOWING" if isinstance(range_[1], RangeDays) else "%s FOLLOWING")
        % (self.process(elements.literal(range_[1]), **kw),),
    )


SQLCompiler._format_frame_clause = _format_frame_clause



Base = declarative_base()


class A(Base):

    __tablename__ = "a"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "test"}

    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    category = Column(Integer)
    record_date = Column(Date)
    example_value = Column(Integer)


dbapi="mysqlconnector"
engine = create_engine(f"mysql+{dbapi}://root:pass@localhost:3306/test", echo=True)
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

session.add(A(record_date=date(2022, 5, 1), category=1, example_value=1))
session.add(A(record_date=date(2022, 5, 2), category=1, example_value=2))
session.add(A(record_date=date(2022, 5, 3), category=1, example_value=3))
session.commit()

stmt = select(
    func.SUM(A.example_value).over(
        partition_by=A.category,
        order_by=A.record_date,
        range_=(RangeDays(-2), RangeDays(-1)),
    )
)

print(f"statement:\n```sql\n{stmt}\n```")

ret = session.execute(stmt).scalar()
print(ret)
````

STATEMENT:

```
SELECT sum(test.a.example_value) OVER (PARTITION BY test.a.category ORDER BY test.a.record_date RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL %(param_1)s DAY PRECEDING AND INTERVAL %(param_2)s DAY PRECEDING) AS anon_1 
FROM test.a
{'param_1': '2', 'param_2': '1'}
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for this - pretty serious stuff! Sadly I'm still getting the same error: `(mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) Failed processing pyformat-parameters; Python 'rangedays' cannot be converted to a MySQL type`. I can see the SQL now contains `INTERVAL` and `DAY`: `SQL: SELECT sum(test.a.example_value) OVER (PARTITION BY test.a.category ORDER BY test.a.record_date RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL %(param_1)s DAY PRECEDING AND INTERVAL %(param_2)s DAY PRECEDING) AS anon_1 
FROM test.a`. However, it looks like there's still something missing :(

Comment: I can see that `_old_format_frame_clause` isn't actually used - could this be causing the problem?

Comment: tested it on docker with `mysql:8.0.29-oracle` for db, `mysql-connector-python==8.0.29` (using `mysqlconector` as in the snippet) and `SQLAlchemy==1.4.36` in `python==3.8.12`

The original `_old_format_frame_clause` is not required, as all its former logic is included in the patched version. I think depending on the sqlalchemy version youmight need to patch something else...

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm running on a quite different config so will have to set up a new virtual env